# Is it possible to use Bitlocker from a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, bitlocker

Currently, I'm using a Windows machine to create a VHD with 2 partitions, one clear text and one encrypted with Bitlocker. I would like to move this process to a Linux container. Is it possible to run Bitlocker on Linux container if it has .NET core loaded onto it?

I've taken a look at Dislocker, but I'm worried about speed in comparison.

Comment: Why do you believe .NET Core has something to do with BitLocker?  If you are worried about BitLocker performance you will want to stay native Windows.  Why is this tagged as .NET 4.0 by the way?

Comment: I was initially led to believe that Bitlocker was tied with .NET core instead of just being a Windows process. A lot more reading made me realize that was entirely wrong.

TL;DR: wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you can use BitLocker on Linux. Did not try any of them, though. Maybe someone else will add details.

- Dislocker (as you already mentioned)
- libbde (AFAIK read-only mounting)
- cryptsetup seems to have (experimental) support for BitLocker since 2.3.0 https://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2020-February/006346.html